# Laravel CRUD explanation

Tags: php, laravel

In my application, I have a link between User and Profile and Profile and User, a one to one relation. This is so the relationship can be accessed from either model.

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'user_username');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_username', 'username');
}
```

Essentially you can access the relations by referencing the method that defines the relationship.

So I could do either `$user->profile` or `$profile->user` to get any related information.

When a user goes to a particular page they should be able to view and edit their profile so I defined a GET and a POST route.

I have routes like the following:

```
Route::get('/profile_edit/{user}','Editable\ProfileController@edit');
Route::post('/profile_edit/{user}','Editable\ProfileController@update');
```

Displaying a form

```
public function edit(User $user)
{    
   return view('editable.people.profile', compact('user'));
}
```

This method gets the profile information by searching the users table by the given wildcard, so it essentially does `SELECT * FROM {wildcard}`.

Updating a profile

In the `ProfileController` a method was automatically generated as it started life as a resource controller.

```
public function update(Request $request, Profile $profile)
{
    // ...
}
```

The reason I'm struggling is because many examples of routes I've seen are human readable and make sense from a simple CRUD perspective, like the below:

```
/posts -> show all posts
/posts{id} -> get a post by ID
/posts{id}/update -> get a post by ID and go to the update script
```

If I don't want to use many slugs in the URL is there a way just to grab the profile from the user and then update that?

In the example I gave of

`public function update(Request $request, Profile $profile)`

The method is looking for an instance of Profile but as my URL isn't `/edit/{profile}` do I even need to pass in the second parameter?

Could I not just do the following?

```
 public function update(Request $request, Profile $profile)
{
    $user = App\User::find($request->username);
    $profile = Profile::where('user_username', $user->username);

    $profile->background = $request->get('background');
    $profile->skills = $request->get('skills');
    $profile->user_username = $profile->user->username;

   $profile->save();
}
```

Comment: Is the profile editing functionality for a authenticated user? or is it something for the admin, where they can modify any user's profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've setup the Eloquent `One-to-One` relationship correctly (via migration as well as model); and let's say you are after implementing view/edit profile functionality for the *authenticated* user, you can do something like this:

**Routes**

```
Route::get('profile_edit', 'ProfileController@view');
Route::post('profile_edit', 'ProfileController@update');
```

**Controller**

```
public function view()
{
    $profile = auth()->user()->profile;

    return return view('editable.people.profile', compact('profile'));
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    // don't forget to do request validation here...

    $user = auth()->user();
    $profile = $user->profile;

    if (!$profile) {
        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->user_id = $user->id;
    }

    $profile->background = $request->get('background');
    $profile->skills = $request->get('skills');
    $profile->user_username = $user->username;

    $profile->save();

    // redirect or set success etc...
}
```

---

However, if you are working from an admin's perspective, where an administrator is wanting to view or edit the profile of a known user, you can do something like this using eager loading:

**Routes**

```
Route::get('profile_edit/{user_id}', 'ProfileController@view');
Route::post('profile_edit/{user_id}', 'ProfileController@update');
```

**Controller**

```
public function view($user_id)
{
    $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->with('profile')->first();

    if (!$user) {
        throw new Exception('User with id '. $user_id .' does not exist.');
    }

    $profile = $user->profile;

    return return view('editable.people.profile', compact('profile'));
}

public function update($user_id, Request $request)
{
    // don't forget to do request validation here...

    $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->with('profile')->first();

    if (!$user) {
        throw new Exception('User with id '. $user_id .' does not exist.');
    }

    $profile = $user->profile;

    if (!$profile) {
        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->user_id = $user->id;
    }

    $profile->background = $request->get('background');
    $profile->skills = $request->get('skills');
    $profile->user_username = $user->username;

    $profile->save();

    // redirect or set success etc...
}
```

Comment: I will update my question but I think now that actually makes sense

Comment: Also, in my other example where it had Request $request, Profile $profile, is that because it was expecting something like edit/{profile} where the slug is an instance of Profile?

Comment: Setting `Profile $profile` along with `Request $request` in the argument is known as route model binding - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Ah, so basically as I'm not passing a slug that references the Profile in the route, it makes a lot of sense that I wouldn't need it.

I'm definately just going to bookmark the Laravel documentation.